# What is the performance overhead of XADisk for read and write operations?

Tags: xadisk

What does XADisk do in addition to reading/writing from the underlying file? How does that translate into a percentage of the read/write throughput (approximately)?

Answer (score 0):

depends on the size, if large set the flag "heavyWrite" as true while opening the xaFileOutputStream.

test with 500 files of size 1MB each. Below is the amount of time taken, averaged over 10 executions...

```
Java IO - 37.5 seconds
Java NIO - 24.8 seconds
XADisk - 30.3 seconds
```